# Odoo: Is there a way to have different tax rates (VAT) on purchase and on selling the product?

Tags: odoo, erp

I am developing a system using the Odoo framework for a customer that sells antique and vintage home decorations and furniture. Because she buys most of her products of private individuals she doesn't pay any tax on purchase of her products.

But as she sells them in her store and makes a commercial profit off of it she has to sell the products with tax included. I already took a look at fiscal positions but it's only possible to change the tax rate per product I think.

Does anyone know how I can implement this?

I tried using the fiscal positions to change the tax rates of products but it only enables me to differentiate between products, not between purchase and sale of the product.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, because you already were on the right path. Use fiscal positions. First you have to decide which are the common cases to define in Odoo: either purchasing or selling. Why? Because you configure Odoo's products for the common case, for example setting taxes for this cases directly in the products (and the global setting). And for all other cases you use fiscal positions, to map common taxes (and accounts) to "special" taxes (and accounts). So in your case you either need one fiscal position for selling or for purchasing.